# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'xpath issue

Tags: python, lxml, python-requests

I am trying to capture a value which is in "//html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[17]/font" through xpath. I am not sure what wrong i am doing but when running the below code i am getting the error message "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'xpath'" Can you please help me

```
import smtplib
import requests
#import bs4
from lxml import html
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def login():
        url = "http://172.16.3.16/bkg/nimble/newsite_airfail_isimba_dom.php"
        r = requests.get(url, auth=('stats', 'Stats'))
        page = r.text
        return page


def extractfailure():
        loginpage = login()
        fail = loginpage.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[17]/font')
        print fail

if __name__ == '__main__':
        extractfailure()
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters i am not using it anywhere. Was trying to experiment but now removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have forgotten to *parse* the response body.

You need to actually use the `lxml.html` parser somewhere before you can use XPath expressions:

```
def extractfailure():
    loginpage = html.fromstring(login())
    fail = loginpage.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[17]/font')
    print fail
```

Take into account that browsers insert `<tbody>` elements if missing from the document. LXML does not insert these, so your browser-sourced XPath expression may be wrong.

Comment: i validated the xpath "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[17]/font" and this seems to be correct. Let try running your code.

Comment: The path may be valid XPath syntax but it is not going to work for the object tree LXML builds from the HTML; most likely there are no actual `<tbody>` elements.

Comment: Hi Martijn, what is your purposed solution for this. What is your way to code this ?

Comment: That's too broad to answer; it depends on the HTML document.

Comment: I tried the code and although it ran successfully without errors but there was no output. Just a blank []

Comment: Yes, because your XPath doesn't match the actual HTML object tree.

Comment: I tried this "/html/body/table//tr/td[2]/table//tr[2]/td[17]/font" and have also removed the Tbody. I am getting the output as "[<Element font at 0x28b1158>]" not sure what does that mean.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are getting the below output when using the xpath

```
[<Element font at 0xeee158>]
```

its because you have not given the text() to capture the text with the xpath which goes as shown below

```
//html/body/table//tr/td[2]/table//tr[2]/td[17]/font/text()
```

My issue is now resolved thanks to @Martijn Pieters

Here is the full code

```
def extractfailure():
    loginpage = html.fromstring(login())
    fail = loginpage.xpath('//html/body/table//tr/td[2]/table//tr[2]/td[17]/font/text()')
    failoutput = fail
    print failoutput
```